# AndroidManifest.xml trouble in the code using ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION I kept changing the program around and now I cannot figure out what went wrong

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-maps, mobile

My program was up and running completely. Now it seems like there is something wrong in the AndroidManifest.xml I tried tinkering around with the code and added custom markers and a few other things. I think at one point I did something to the AndroidManifest and it is not working as it should work. The app launches and I am able to login but once the maps API begins, then it crashes and I do not know what went wrong...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.vuapp">
<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the "MyLocation" functionality.
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.vumap">

    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>


    <meta-data
        android:name="preloaded_fonts"
        android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
</activity>

</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed the `>` in your permission.

just copy this :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: I tried to edit it and now it says: "The element type "uses-permission" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</uses-permission>".

Comment: You forgot to put `</manifest>` after `</application>` tag  @AmandaW